# Add a default user picture like Gmail Android App

Tags: android, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, gmail, user-profile

How to dynamically create a user picture from the first letter of his user name like Gmail App on android does?

[image]

I'm working under **Django and Bootstrap**, But i'm open for **any solution** in any language or framwork.

Now I'm managing user profile by using a default picture for new users

[image]

and letting them uploading their own profile picture if they want to.

> class Profile(models.Model):
>
> ```
> user = models.OneToOneField(User)
> ....
>
> def get_picture(self):
>
>     no_picture = settings.STATIC_URL + 'img/user.png'
>     try:
>         filename = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/profile_pictures/' + self.user.username + '.jpg'
>         picture_url = settings.MEDIA_URL + 'profile_pictures/' + self.user.username + '.jpg'
>         if os.path.isfile(filename):
>             return picture_url
>         else:
>             return no_picture
>     except Exception, e:
>         return no_picture
> .....
> ```

PS: I can do that by uploading 26 picture with different Letters, but here i want a dynamic solution for some reasons

Comment: English alphabets are 26 in number.

Comment: You might be looking for a tool like this: [django-avatar](http://django-avatar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - which has a [default url](http://django-avatar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#global-settings)

Answer (score 1):

For context,

I do not believe the Gmail Android app is actually generating an image. This effect can be achieved in Android with the following shape as a drawable background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#f5d2c3" />
     <size android:width="75dp"
          android:height="75dp" />
</shape>
```

And apply it to a textview:

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/square_background"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="J" />
```

A better solution would be for you to just center text in a `div` with a background applied. This is much easier then generating an image for something so simple.

Comment: Thank you for the Android code.
for the div solution you mean that i have to write one Css style to center the lettre and 26 diffrents Css styles named labes_X and specify a background color for each of them ?

Comment: @imanis_tn If you have a set of specific background colors you want associated with each letter, then yes, you will either have to specify 26 of them in CSS or you could do it in Javascript or even server side. You could also auto-generate CSS colors in Javascript if you want it to be dynamic.